# Lost network device on upgrade to 15.10 on test VM

Tags: networking, 15.10

I just upgraded my test and development VM to 15.10, and I lost my network device `eth0`.

`ifconfig` just reports the loopback device adapter, yet `lspci` reports the Intel network controller is there.

Comment: Close voters: both the question and the answer may be useful for future visitors. I do not see any reason for closing.

Comment: Please could someone clarify why this question is off topic?  15.10 is upon us.

Comment: ... especially since the released version (which then is not a "development version" anymore) exposes the same problem. Took me hours to learn at least some basics about udev a.s.o. Not nice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The network adapter was renamed from `eth0` to `enp0s3`.

I found this out by using `dmesg | grep eth0`.

I then updated the file `/etc/network/interfaces` by changing `eth0` to `enp0s3`.

Comment: `enp0s3` is the name of an Ethernet device as given by the new version of udev, which enables stateless persistant network interface names. The strange thing is that it shouldn't have happened during upgrade, only on fresh installation. Can you please provide more details about the upgrade?

Comment: Ubuntu server, not `network-manager`